# Kmeans is not producing an elbow

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-computing, k-means

I have a data frame of about 300,000 unique product names and I am trying to use k means to cluster similar names together. I used sklearn's tfidfvectorizer to vectorize the names and convert to a tf-idf matrix.

Next I ran k means on the tf-idf matrix with number of clusters ranging from 5 to 25. Then I plotted the inertia for each # of clusters.

Based on the plot am I approaching the problem wrong? What are some takeaways from this if there is no distinct elbow?

[image]

Comment: Real world problems don't always follow the text book. If you don't see an elbow it doesn't necessarily mean that you are doing something wrong. You can try even more clusters (say a few hundred) and see if this changes anything. If not, just use the number of clusters that performed best.

Comment: thanks @tttthomasssss

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because k-means w=th TF-IDF doesn't work well on such short text such as product names.

Not seeing an elbow is an indication that the results aren't good.